# Reg Ex left padding with zeros

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, alias

I have product image URLs:
eg. www.example.com/product_images/12345/large.jpg

Now, due to the 'ext3 server' i have a 32,000 file per folder limit, and guess what, i'm very close to having 32,000 products. I can't change the server.

I don't want the URL itself to change so was looking to create a reg ex that I could use in either an AliasMatch to produce the following...

www.example.com/product_images/1/large.jpg => 
www.example.com/new_product_images/0000/0001/large.jpg

and

www.example.com/product_images/123456/large.jpg => 
www.example.com/new_product_images/0012/3456/large.jpg

I envisage it padding the number to 8 characters with leading zeros, and then chopping it in half. but my reg ex skill aren't that great... I'm stuck with the padding.

thank you for your time!

Jon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want padding, you could do this with multiple rules, matching various lengths

```
RewriteRule ^/product_images/(.{1})(.{4})/(.*)$ new_product_images/000$1/$2/$3
RewriteRule ^/product_images/(.{2})(.{4})/(.*)$ new_product_images/00$1/$2/$3
RewriteRule ^/product_images/(.{3})(.{4})/(.*)$ new_product_images/0$1/$2/$3
RewriteRule ^/product_images/(.{4})(.{4})/(.*)$ new_product_images/$1/$2/$3
```

Or, just have your folders be 1 or 2 or 3 characters (no padding) and use 1 rule for everything.

```
RewriteRule ^/product_images/(.+)(.{4})/(.*)$ new_product_images/$1/$2/$3
```

This would map

- 12345    -> /1/2345
- 123456   -> /12/3456
- 1234567  -> /123/4567
- 12345678 -> /1234/5678

This doesn't keep the folders in order, but its a simpler rule.

You could also use a fixed length prefix - for example, anything that starts with a single digit is in a different folder. Here's an example with 2 digits

This would map

- 123      -> /12/3
- 12345    -> /12/345
- 123456   -> /12/3456
- 234567   -> /23/4567
- 2345678  -> /23/45678

Using this, 2 characters cuts your problem by a factor of 100.

The only problem is IDs less than 100 - one solution might be to leave those in the existing folder (product_images), and your RewriteRule only applies to IDs 100+.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/product_images/(..)(.+)/(.*)$ new_product_images/$1/$2/$3
```

Comment: No need for the RewriteCond it is overkill as images less than 100 will not match the regex in the rule and so will not be rewritten by default.

Comment: you're a star. that looks brillant. I'll shall give it a go today. thanks a lot!